# Firebase Function multi-type batching

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there currently any built in methods, or workaround, for doing batch processing of different types of database/service work?

For example, i have a need to do multiple things and either have them ALL complete or if one fails then roll all work back. By multi-type i mean:

1. Increment counter in `firestore`
2. Create a `Google Cloud Tasks Queue` item
3. Write a new Record to `firestore` collection

If any of these fail i need to roll them all back. I have used firestore batch writes before but that doesn't support what i need in doing the Google Cloud Tasks Queue work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use transactions to pull together multiple operations atomically in Firestore, but there is no way to guarantee atomicity across multiple different systems. What you would need to do is something like:

1. In a transaction, increment counter, write new record, and somewhere capture that a Cloud Task item is pending scheduling along with the current time.
2. Schedule the Cloud Task item.
3. Mark the pending item as complete.

You would then have a scheduled function that periodically looks for old tasks that were supposed to have been scheduled but weren't. For each of those, clean up the Firestore data or retry as you see fit.